# Using jquery.append() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

What's wrong in my code that the append method dont work? I do get the alert but the actual method that will append is not working. Please see the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    if (!document.getElementById('my_options').value)
    {
        alert('here');
        jQuery('#my_options').append('<span id="option_id_error" class="errors">Error</span>');
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="my_options" name="my_options">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="my_options2" name="my_options2">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="my_options3" name="my_options3">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

The select in the form is dynamically generated. If none is selected on the dropdown box, it will display the span error message. So my expected result is this:

```
<select id="my_options" name="my_options">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select> <span>Error</span>
```

I don't need to add something on the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to add this `<span>` element just next to `<select>` you may use .after(..) method:

```
jQuery('#my_options').after('<span id="option_id_error" class="errors">Error</span>');
```

Comment: Hi, yes.. I actually tried it before you made your response and i found it out working. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not correct as a SPAN item is not valid within an SELECT item.

If you try to add a new option for example it will work

```
$('#my_options').append('<option value="5">item</option>');
```

what you can do is to wrap the select item inside a DIV as showed below

```
<div id="option1">
    <select id="my_options" name="my_options">
           <option value="">--Select--</option>
           <option value="1">Option 1</option>
           <option value="2">Option 2</option>
           <option value="3">Option 3</option>
           <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

than you can do:

```
$('#option1').append('<span id="option_id_error" class="errors">Error</span>');
```

you can see it working at the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/LGkWp/

Comment: yes yes, it already have the # sign.. I gonna edit my post above.

Comment: I miss an apostrophe try again

Comment: hmmm.. what will be append is not an option value but a <span>Error</span>. I wanna add it after </select>. The result will be like this, <select id="my_options" name="my_options"><option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option></select>  <span>Error</span>

Comment: you CANNOT add a SPAN inside a drop down list element(it wont be shown)

Comment: is there any way that i can add a span after the </select>? Look like the function i have, will add options in the dropdown box.

Comment: You are right on that @massimiliano. But the problem here, is that i cant just wrap it with <div></div>. The page is dynamically generated. So, I really need it to base in the <select id="my_options"></select>. If that is found, I need to append a <span>Error</span> if nothing is selected in the my_options.

Comment: there is not way to add a span inside a SELECT item because it would not be a valid HTML. You can add the div dynamically using JQuery anyway.
You didn't mention anyway it was a dynamic generated HTML so please be more specific next time